# How do I define a python size generic?

Tags: python, python-typing

I want to use a non-type parameter in Python, somewhat like this c++ snippet (this is only an example).

```cpp
template<int SIZE>
class SizedData {
  void add(std::array<float,SIZE> point) { /* do stuff */ }
};
```

But in python, but as far as I can tell typing only supports typed generics parameters.

I want something like this, so that static analysis can find invalid arguments.

```py
# Warning: This is not valid python

SIZE = SizeVar('SIZE', int) # allow any int as a valid value
class SizedData(Generic[SIZE]):
  def add(point: Annotated[Sequence[float], SIZE]) -> None:
    pass # do stuff
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question... can you explain what you're trying to achieve in a generic (non-C++) way?